# Need to copy a file via puppet only if a Windows MSI package is not installed

Tags: windows, windows-installer, puppet

I'm new using puppet on Windows.
I'm trying to install a MSI package from a shared folder on our network, but do to permissions, the shared folder is "read" only, it does not have "execute" permissions so when the puppet agent runs and tries to install the MS, it fails.

What I want to do is to copy the MSI installer to a local directory ONLY if the package needs to be installed.

This is how I'm installing the package and copying to a local dir:

```
class app_install {
    package { '7-Zip 9.38 (x64 edition)':
        provider => windows,
        ensure   => installed,
        source => 'c:\\temp\7zip_testInstall.msi',
        install_options => ['INSTALLDIR=C:\apps64\7-Zip'],
    }
    file { 'c:/temp/7zip_testInstall.msi':
        ensure => 'file',
        mode   => '0660',
        group  => 'Domain Users',
        source => 'c:\\temp\7zip_testInstall.msi',
     }
```

### }

When I run puppet and it finds that the package is not installed, it copies the file to a c:\temp, then proceeds to install the package. This is the expected behavior.
On subsequent runs of the puppet agent, it finds that the package is already installed, so it skips the installation, but then proceeds to copy the installer to c:\temp again if the installer is missing from c:\temp - given the fact that this is a temp folder, it gets purged every so often.

What I'm trying to avoid is to copy the installer if the package is already installed.

I'm not sure how to go about it.

Please advise and thanks!

Fr3edom21.

Comment: Common problem with Puppet. Easiest workaround is to store installers in non-temporary locations.

Comment: Thanks Felix,  I thought about doing that, but didn't want to keep two copies of a package on the local machine. One copy as the installed app, and one copy of the installer itself.

Comment: You could try and build this using the WiP [transition](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-transition) module. Please let us know if and how this works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to answer my on question.

Instead of using the "file resource" to copy the MSI from the network share to c:\temp, I ended up executing a file copy via the "exec resource" only if the Uninstall registry key version value for said program is missing.
Like this:

```
exec { 'copy MSI to c:\temp':
command => 'C:\\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "copy \\server\repo\7zip_testinstall.msi c:\\temp"',
unless => 'C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{23170F69-40C1-2702-0938-00000100000 /f 9.38.00.0',
}
```

---

I hope this helps anyone with similar problem.

A couple of things to consider if you go this route:

- If you are on the 32-bit version of Puppet on a 64-bit machine, `C:\Windows\System32` is actually redirected (by Windows' [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx)) to `C:\Windows\SystemWOW64` where the 32-bit system32 binaries live. If you want the 64-bit system32 binaries, you should consider using `c:\Windows\sysnative`. If you are on the 64-bit version of Puppet, you don't fall subject to this issue and **should not** use sysnative as it doesn't exist. If you are on Puppet 3.7.3+, you can use the [`$system32` fact](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/core_facts.html#system32) to handle mixed environments. For more information see [Handling File Paths on Windows](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.7/reference/lang_windows_file_paths.html#file-system-redirection-when-running-32-bit-puppet-on-64-bit-windows).
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` is one of four different possible locations. Again with 32-bit Puppet, you are subject to registry redirection unless you are using the Registry module. If the software can be installed as 32-bit, you may need to check whether it also exists at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` as well if you are running 64-bit Puppet or not subject to the registry redirector.

Fr3edom21.

Comment: you should accept this as your answer if you feel it answers your question

Comment: That will generally work, however there are a couple of things to note. I will edit the answer so you will see those.

Comment: That should do it. :)